# How to create a histogram from a list of ranges/intervals/segments?

Tags: numpy, matplotlib

I have data given as a list of intervals, i.e., `(s1, e1), (s2, e2), ..., (sn, en)`. I would like to calculate (and draw) the histogram of the values within these ranges/intervals.

I know I can do something like:

```
points = [ j for i in intervals for j in range(i[0], i[1] + 1) ]
plt.hist(points)
```

However, that requires enumerating the actual values in the interval which may be a problem for large intervals. This is also not applicable if the range is float and I would need to draw a KDE.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you wish to avoid expanding each interval beforehand - which is what `plt.hist` normally requires, what you can do instead is implement the counting operation yourself.

Consider that you have 3 intervals `(200,500)`, `(300,600)` and `(200,400)`. Enumerating each would mean having 803 values in total. However, there are actually only 401 unique values overall. A more extreme case: if you have 10 same intervals `(200,500)`, enumerating each means 3010 values in total, even though there are only 301 unique values.

By this fact, you can preemptively create an array containing all the unique values, alongside another array to keep count. Then going through each interval `(i,j)`, you can do some operation like `count[i:j+1]+=1`. So rather than expanding each `(i,j)` interval into many duplicate values, you're only using the `i` and `j` to slice into an array.

Moving on, if you read the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) for `plt.hist`, you'll see that there's a note on how to use the `weights` parameter for histograms where the values have already been counted.

Putting all of this together would be something like:

```
def inter_hist(ivls, n_bins = 10):
    imin, imax = ivls.min(), ivls.max()
    values = np.arange(imin,imax+1)
    counts = np.zeros(values.shape)
    for i,j in (ivls-imin): 
        counts[i:j+1] += 1
 
    bins = np.arange(imin, imax+1, ((imax-imin)/n_bins))
    plt.hist(values, bins, weights=counts)

intervals = np.array([[2,10],[6,12],[8,16],[20,30]])
inter_hist(intervals)
```

[image: hist]

Lastly, I've only accounted for integers here, which gives several conveniences. In the case of floating ranges, some tweaks might be needed when generating values or slicing into counts, although the overall process should be the same.

Comment: For anyone reaching this page, the (current) tweak for float is to drop the floating point part for large enough numbers (for me it is hundreds and up) and multiply by a power of 10 for lower ranges to get them into the hundreds. This can later be "removed" by dividing. I used numpy's histogram for the calculations and matplotlib's bar chart to display the result (dividing if needed beforehand)